# Create Function for Average of Specified Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please help!

I need to create a function in VBA that allows me to return an average based on a specified range of cells.

For this function, I want to specify the range of cells, have the code ID the active cell within that range, and then average the cells above and below based off of the active cell. The image attached shows what I am trying to do.

[image]

Here is the VBA Function I have thus far, but I cannot seem to get it to work at all:

VBA:

```
Function SpecialAVERAGE(rng As Range, LowerBound As Integer, UpperBound As Integer) As Double

Dim Origin As Range
Dim Total As Double
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Lower As Long
Dim Upper As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long

Set Origin = ActiveCell

For Each Cell In rng
    Lower = Range(Cell.Offset(-LowerBound, 0), Cells(Origin.Row, 1))
    A = wf.Sum(Lower)
    Upper = Range(Cell.Offset(UpperBound, 0), Cells(Origin.Row, 1))
    B = wf.Sum(Upper)
    Total = Total + Cell.Value + A + B
    Count = Count + 1

Next Cell

SpecialAVERAGE = Total / Count

End Function
```

Any direction is greatly appreciated!! 
I understand that =AVERAGE(OFFSET(.... ))) may help with this, but I haven't found the solution there either.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

No need to overcomplicate - just use the lower and upper boundary to widen your row values for `WorksheetFunction.Average`, and use one cell (instead of the whole column) for the reference range:

```
Function SPECIALAVERAGE(rng As Range, LowerBound As Integer, UpperBound As Integer) As Double

    SPECIALAVERAGE = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(rng.Row - LowerBound, rng.Column), Cells(rng.Row + UpperBound, rng.Column)))

End Function
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give this a try!!

Comment: Did exactly what I needed! Thank you!!